# Are there $N_n$ lattices generalizing the $N_5$ lattice?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, lattice-orders

$M_3$ and $N_5$ lattice, respectively, is a widely used notation for these two lattices.

I'm wondering what the indices mean.
For the M case, I found in the book of *B. A. Davey, H. A. Priestley, Introduction to Lattices and Order*, the definition of $M_n$ lattice (= lattice of height two with n atoms, $n \in \mathbb N$), which completely answers my question for $M_3$.

So my question is: Is there an analogous (standard) definition of $N_n$ lattice (or partially ordered set), such that $N_5$ is just the special case for $n = 5$?

My question is a little bit related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623531/the-lattices-m-3-and-n-5/4623693#4623693).
But in contrast to this question, I do not care where the "M" or "N" comes from.

Comment: I suppose if someone will ever find it useful, they'll define it. I never saw such a definition. Perhaps a natural generalization like for $M_n$ would be a $N_m$, for $m\geq5$ being a non-modular lattice with $m$ elements $0,1,a_1,\ldots,a_{m-3},b$, where $0\leq x\leq 1$ for all $x$, and there are maximal chains $$0<a_1<\cdots<a_{m-3}<1$$ and $0<b<1$. But the extra elements could also be divided by both maximal chains...

Comment: Thank you, @amrsa. Yes, this might be the most likely interpretation. But then I would call it $N_2$ rather than $N_5$. Anyway, as you said, who ever will find it useful ... And I understood your comment as that this is certainly not a standard definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a definition for $N_n$ in the literature which reduces to the usual $N_5$ when $n=5$. See Diagram 11 on page 42 of
[Equational bases and nonmodular lattice varieties](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-174-00/S0002-9947-1972-0313141-1/S0002-9947-1972-0313141-1.pdf) by Ralph McKenzie, Transactions of the AMS,
Volume 174, December 1972.

I have a better drawing of a typical member of this sequence of lattices in [one of my papers](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s000120050134?sharing_token=n7L8mH7HNTBjf56p9eJX8ve4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY7jMGHWV5d0iYG0bSqZsXeuaeZXAb6XqnkPLFmatCldzgUOYgonvpReRC1xMGltxNFvfwoC3c91WsHqDY0WctK9RfljqN-zSaIOvO3AucvGPQ%3D%3D) (see the front page of the article). I renumbered the sequence for my paper so that $N_0$ is the first lattice in the sequence, and it is the lattice that one usually calls $N_5$.  Therefore, if McKenzie's sequence of lattices is $N_n^{\textrm{McK}}$, $n\geq 5$, then my renumbered sequence is $N_{n-5}^{\textrm{KK}}$.

These lattices form a natural sequence of projective, subdirectly irreducible lattices. This combination of properties is interesting because if $L$ is a projective, subdirectly irreducible lattice, then the class of lattices that do not contain $L$ as a sublattice is closed under $H, S$, and $P$, hence is a variety. It is well-known that the class of lattices that do not contain $N_5$ as a sublattice is a variety of lattices, but less well-known that the same statement is true for $N_6^{\textrm{McK}}$, $N_7^{\textrm{McK}}$, $N_8^{\textrm{McK}}$, etc.

Comment: Great, that's a much more detailed and accurate answer than I was hoping for. Thanks a lot!